# BlocBuilder not updating after change

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a bloc to manage all the quotations in the application. The quotation class, bloc, and events are given below:

I have a form in which on selecting the text field, I show a list view to the user, and the value of the selected list view is assigned to the bloc and displayed in the text field.

Everything works fine but when I assign the value to the bloc variable and return it back to the form the text field value does update BUT ONLY FOR SINGLE TIME. If I do select some other list option for the same or another field the field value doesn't update.

CAN ANYONE SUGGEST A FIX?

I have a custom textField created as shown below and I'm calling this inside a bloc builder:

```
BlocBuilder<QuoteBloc, QuoteState>(builder: (context, state) {
  if (state is QuoteInitialized) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        BookingFormField(
          labelText: "Flying From",
          onTap: () => Navigator.push(
            context,
            AirportCityPlaceSelection.route(
              'tq-fb-flight-from',
            ),
          ),
          controller: TextEditingController(
            text: BlocProvider.of<QuoteBloc>(context)
                .quote
                .flight
                .flightFrom,
          ),
        ),
        BookingFormField(
          labelText: "Flying To",
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              AirportCityPlaceSelection.route(
                'tq-fb-flight-to',
              ),
            );
          },
          controller: TextEditingController(
            text: BlocProvider.of<QuoteBloc>(context)
                .quote
                .flight
                .flightTo,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}),



class BookingFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function onTap;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final String labelText;

  BookingFormField({
    @required this.onTap,
    @required this.controller,
    @required this.labelText,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 10.0,
        bottom: 10.0,
      ),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        readOnly: true,
        onTap: () => onTap(),
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.copyWith(
              fontSize: 13.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I'm updating the value in the list view which is a new screen:

```
BlocProvider.of<QuoteBloc>(context).quote.flight.flightFrom = value;
BlocProvider.of<QuoteBloc>(context).add(QuoteUpdated());
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Quote Class:-

```
part 'flight.dart';
part 'car.dart';
part 'cruise.dart';
part 'hotel.dart';
part 'visa.dart';
part 'insurance.dart';
part 'transfer.dart';

class Quote {
  String name;
  String contactNumber;
  String email;
  Flight flight;
  Car car;
  Hotel hotel;
  Cruise cruise;
  Transfer transfer;
  Visa visa;
  Insurance insurance;    
// Constructors & other functions    
}
```

The events related to the quote bloc are:

```
abstract class QuoteEvent extends Equatable {
  List<Object> get props => [];
}


class QuoteUpdated extends QuoteEvent {
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

The quote State is

```
abstract class QuoteState extends Equatable {
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class QuoteInitialized extends QuoteState {
  final Quote quote;

  QuoteInitialized({
    @required this.quote,
  });

  List<Object> get props => [this.quote];
}

class QuoteSubmissionInProgress extends QuoteState {}

class QuoteSubmissionSuccessful extends QuoteState {}

class QuoteSubmissionFailed extends QuoteState {}
```

Quote Bloc:

```
class QuoteBloc extends Bloc<QuoteEvent, QuoteState> {
  final Quote quote;

  QuoteBloc(Quote quote)
      : assert(quote != null),
        this.quote = quote,
        super(QuoteInitialized(quote: quote));

  @override
  Stream<QuoteState> mapEventToState(QuoteEvent event) async* {
    if (event is QuoteUpdated) {
      yield QuoteInitialized(quote: this.quote);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't update state in UI LAYER (send event to bloc)
2. Try to remove equatable in QuoteState or Add Equatable to Quote class

Comment: I already had Equatiable added to the quoted class. Removing the Equitable from the QuoteState seems to fix the issue. Can you explain to me why? Also by "Don't update state in UI LAYER" you mean what I'm doing in the listview?

Comment: Equatable changes your instance hash code and override its (==) equality logic by comparing by it is fields in your instance.
If you dont use equatable, then your instances will be checked equality by its physical address in memory.

Comment: BlocProvider.of<QuoteBloc>(context).quote.flight.flightFrom = value;  
Here you updated your state in ui part.
Instead you should add event in ui part and send value to bloc

Comment: Yes, I could do that. But I have around 7 options, like, flight, hotel, cruise and so on.... for each of them there are around 10 fields that can be updated... All there flight, car, etc are the subtype of quote class. So instead of doing what you suggested, I have defined a single event QuoteUpdated to handle all the changes in quote value.... Do you have any better solution for this??

Comment: For this i would create bloc per feature f.e. InsuranceBloc CarBloc
And listen these blocs in QuoteBloc
Why? As Creator of Flutter bloc wrote that bloc is needed to create per feature not per screen. 
Why?
If Insurance feature is changed, then you should change all your quote bloc instead you could change only one bloc in this example Insurance bloc

However it depends on you))

Answer (score 0):

A guess is that the state is considered to be the same, meaning that the following times you expect updated fields you actually didn't get a new state. Have you verified that you get a new yielded state in the BlocBuilder?

My guess is based on two things. Firstly, that symptom could manifest in that way. Secondly I don't see methods in the Quote class that allow for equals comparison (maybe you have it where you commented out code).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which gave me a headache. I was using a cubit and it won't display a progress bar because the loading state was not set. Since bloc extends cubit you might have the same problem. I had to put a future.delayed before emitting the SearchLoading() state. After this change, the state was set and the progress bar was shown. I had this problem in the debug mode of an Android app as well as in the release build.

```
class SearchCubit extends Cubit<SearchState> {
  final ClubRepository _clubRepository = ClubRepository();
  final log = getLogger("SearchCubit");

  SearchCubit() : super(SearchInitial());

  Future<void> getClubs() async {
    try {
      log.d("Fetch clubs");
      await Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1));
      emit(SearchLoading());
      final List<Club> clubs = await _clubRepository.fetch();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
      emit(SearchLoaded(clubs));
    } catch (err, stacktrace) {
      emit(SearchError("Retrieving data from API failed!"));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is happening because your `Quote` class does not extend `Equatable`. Please refer to the [FAQs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=state-not-updating) for more information